# Logical checkboxes in treelist

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, observer-pattern, treelist

I've got a treelist with checkboxes.
This treelist holds many items of the same type, distributed across several layers.

Now if the user unchecks one item, all items of the same type shall be unchecked as well.
Can you give me advice how to implement this?
Would the observer pattern be a possible solution? And how is this to use here?

Comment: There are many readymade controls available. By type do you mean it should check or uncheck child items?

Comment: Which readymade controls do you mean? and how to use them. Do you have an example or a link?
What i mean is that if any item (example: Dogs) is checked, all other items of the same type (Dogs) shall be checked as well, doesnt matter if parent of child...

Comment: If it is not parent child relationship, you can apply same class called "dogs" and on change you make them selected/ deselected.